# How to delete a particular line from file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-manipulation

```
def deleteEmployee(self,code,name):
  with open("employee.data","r+") as file:
  # data=file.readlines()
    for num, i in enumerate(file,1): 
       print(i)
       a=i[:len(i)-1]
       if str(a)==str(code):
          print("found at",num)
          file.seek(num)
          file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

I just want to write a file handling code. Here I define delete function where I want to delete particular code if exists inside the file but it's not working.

Comment: Lines don't really *exist* in files, which are just a sequence of characters some of which represent the start of a new "line". It's very hard to remove a line in place, therefore; you're better off reading in the lines, filtering out the ones you don't want, then writing the whole result back out over the old file.

Comment: but it's not feasible to create a new file again and again whenever user delete a data from file

Comment: Why isn't that feasible? Also that's not really what I'm suggesting, I'm suggesting you replace all of the content not create a new file.

Comment: But probably what you actually want is a *database* if you think you're going to be changing the data a lot.

Comment: Ok  please give me a hint or code if you have code related to file that replace data in new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should achieve what you want:

```
def deleteEmployee(self,code,name):
    with open("employee.data","r+") as file:
        new_content = ""
        for num, line in enumerate(file,1): 
            print(line)
            a=line[:-1]
            if str(a)==str(code):
                print("found at ",num)
                new_content += "\n" #Adds newline instead of 'bad' lines
            else:
                new_content += line #Adds line for 'good' lines
        file.seek(0) #Returns to start of file
        file.write(new_content) #Writes cleaned content
        file.truncate() #Deletes 'old' content from rest of file
        file.close()
```